# import Vue from 'vue' imports "different" Vue to different files

Tags: javascript, npm, vuejs2, webpack-2

*This question is probably more about Webpack and ES6 `import` than about Vue.*

I'm writing a Vuex mutation that adds a new `mykey: []` to an object in `state`. This needs to use `Vue.set(state.myobj, 'mykey', [])`, so that the new array gains reactiveness.

However, when I `import Vue from 'vue'` to my mutations.js and use `Vue.set(...)` it doesn't fix the problem (it just does nothing). The problem seems to be that `Vue` is not the same `Vue` that I use in my main js file when creating the Vue object in my main.js file.

I've verified that the problem is related to the way Vue is imported to mutations.js. If I write `window.MY_VUE = Vue` in main.js and then use `window.MY_VUE.set(...)` in mutations.js, the new array works as expected, i.e. when I push to the array, the changes are correctly reflected in DOM. Naturally, comparing `window.MY_VUE === Vue` in mutations.js returns false.

**Am I doing something wrong? What would be the correct way to fix the problem?**

NB: As a workaround, I now replace the object:

```
state.myobj = { ...state.myobj, mykey: [] }
```

I'm using Vue 2.4.2, Vuex 2.4.0 and Webpack 2.7.0. I'm not using Webpack code-splitting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the *immediate* cause. I first noticed that when loading the app, "You are running Vue in development mode." was printed **twice** in the console. They were both from vue.runtime.esm.js:7417, but served from different urls. (Webpack urls, since I was running `npm run dev`.) I noticed I had two `node_modules` directories (at `./` and `../../`), and for some reason Vue was loaded once from both places. Probably I had installed the npm packages somehow in the wrong order. Removing both `node_modules` dirs and running `npm install` again solved the problem: now I can `import Vue from 'vue'` in mutations.js, and `Vue.set(...)` works as expected.

Anyway, I'm still not exactly aware of the actual npm problem or how to not do it again.

Comment: sorrry for asking here an off topic question... but can you maybe tell me which IDE gives best support for VUE? I am nomrally an angular dev. and i just began with vue

Comment: @Atlas I like VSCode with the Vetur extension